# How to add Required validator for Autocomplete combo?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

How to add required field validator to autocomplete box in extjs4, I tried allowBlank:false, but it doesn't work when we enter invalid values.

Comment: Please don't use a ExtJS3 tag when you are referring to ExtJS4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [forceSelection](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-forceSelection) to only allow items from the list